# POSTGRESQL unaccent doesñ't match words with ñ

Tags: postgresql

Hi guys I have a database with medical terms in spanish. Lets say the table `description` has a column called `term`.
If I use the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM description
WHERE unaccent(description.term) ILIKE '%sueño%';
```

The result set is empty buty I know the table has terms with `ñ`. For instance, the query:

```
SELECT *
FROM description
WHERE description.term ILIKE '%sueño%';
```

does return several results.

I need the unaccent extensión to match `á` with `a` for example.
For the moment I'm using this work around, but I think its not efficient:

```
SELECT *
FROM description
WHERE unaccent(description.term) ILIKE '%${CRITERIA}%' OR description.term ILIKE '%${CRITERIA}%';
```

Can anyone help me understand why this happens? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This won't work:**

```
SELECT *
FROM description
WHERE unaccent(description.term) ILIKE '%sueño%';
```

Because `unaccent(description.term)` **does not have `ñ`**. You are using `ILIKE` to compare with an `ñ`. If the "criteria" is going to have accents, then you should use unaccent in both sides.

**This works:**

```
SELECT *
FROM description
WHERE unaccent(description.term) ILIKE unaccent('%sueño%');
```

Comment: Just keep in mind that if you have an index with the column `term`, you will need to add the `unaccent` function to it as well: `CREATE INDEX idx ON description (unaccent(term));`

Comment: I do have an index in that column with `pg_trgm`. Thanks

Comment: `CREATE INDEX idx ON description (unaccent(term));`